# Rotation order for eulers getPitch(), getRoll(), getYaw() from Quaternion in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, quaternions, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

When transforming a quaternion to Euler Angles, usually there has to be a order in which the axes are rotated, like in [this visualization.](http://quaternions.online/)

How does it work for libgdx?

The Quaternion class has the functions

```
getRoll():

Math.asin(MathUtils.clamp(2f * (w*x - z * y), -1f, 1f)) : 
     (float)pole * MathUtils.PI * 0.5f;`

getPitch():

Math.asin(MathUtils.clamp(2f * (w*x - z * y), -1f, 1f)) : 
     (float)pole * MathUtils.PI * 0.5f;`

getYaw():
`
MathUtils.atan2(2f * (y * w + x * z), 1f - 2f * (y * y + x * x)) : 0f;`
```

Where is the order of the resulting angles set, which axes is rotated first,second,third ?

How are these functions related to a quaternion rotation matrix like:
[image]

Why is it that often this Rotationmatrix is given as Inverse /Transposed (equal because of orthogonality) ?

Comment: Ah!, this image is the first that appears on google when you search, and it's the rotation matrix but transposed!

Answer (score 0):

### Rotation order

There are 12 possible orders of rotations possible for using an angle triplet for orientation.

Six of them are called Proper Euler angles, and rest six are called Tait–Bryan angles.

[Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)

Libgdx uses the following order.

1. Rotate by yaw about Y
2. Elevate by pitch towards Y
3. Rotate by roll about obtained direction

---

### Rotation Matrix

Rotation matrices, Quaternions, Euler angles and Axis-Angle representation are different ways to encode rotation/orientation.

They often trade off between storage space and computation cost.

They can be freely converted into each other by means of well defined equations, one of which you mentioned. So these conversion expressions are related to each other.

---

**Edit**
Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It is indeed about Y axis not Z.

I have verified it from the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.java).

---

Libgdx uses [coordinate system](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Coordinate_system) of bullet physics engine. In that system, XZ plane is considered horizontal and Y is considered upwards (not Z). This was the root of my mistake.

Comment: to Yaw about Z: why does the libgdx documentation say, yaw is around Y as here:[getYaw method](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html)  ? Is there a difference between rotate 'about' and 'around' ?

Comment: Wherefrom could you get the libgdx order? Is it implemented in code?

Comment: You can also compare output of gdx `Quaternion` methods to values given by the visualization you mentioned for various rotation orders if you like.

Comment: does it follow the ["x-convention"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) ? considering libgdx COSY, the libgdx rotation order would be YXY. I was still not sure what do you mean by "3. .. obtained direction". The visualisation does offer only ZYX, XYZ, YZX unfortunately.