# Global Translation in libgdx is reset by method calculateTransforms?

Tags: java, libgdx, transformation

In `libgdx`, when performing the following code using a `Model` through `ModelInstance` that has several Nodes (one of them is "Hips"):

```
Matrix4 mtr4 = new Matrix4().idt();
mtr4 = modelInstance.getNode("Hips").globalTransform.cpy();
mtr4 = mtr4.translate(deltaVector3);

modelInstance.getNode("Hips").globalTransform.set(mtr4);

//now, mtr4 still has the same value when:
mtr4 = modInstance.getNode("Hips").globalTransform.cpy();

modelInstance.calculateTransforms();

//after following, mtr4 will be reset to before it was translated with deltaVector3
mtr4 = modInstance.getNode("Hips").globalTransform.cpy();
```

Why is the `mtr4` value set back? Doesn't the `calculateTransforms()` method kind of 'apply' what has been assigned to the Node?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/ModelInstance.html#calculateTransforms--) of the `calculateTransforms` method:

> Calculates the local and world transform of all [Node](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html) instances in this model, recursively. First each [Node.localTransform](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html#localTransform) transform is calculated based on the translation, rotation and scale of each Node. Then each [Node.calculateWorldTransform()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html#calculateWorldTransform--) is calculated, based on the parent's world transform and the local transform of each Node. Finally, the animation bone matrices are updated accordingly.
>
> This method can be used to recalculate all transforms if any of the Node's local properties (translation, rotation, scale) was modified.

So, indeed the `localTransform` and `globalTransform` are recalculated (and thus overwritten) when you call the `calculateTransforms` method (the method naming is kinda obvious for that).

If you want to use the matrices directly, instead of the `translation`, `scale` and `rotation` members, then you have two options:

- Don't call the `calculateTransforms` method, or
- set the [`isAnimated`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html#isAnimated) member to true to inform the `calculateTransforms` method that it should recalculate the matrix for that specific node. For this you should modify the [`localTransform`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html#localTransform) member instead.

If you don't want the Node the inherit its parent transformation then you can set the [`inheritTransform`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html#inheritTransform) member to `false`.

Comment: when `node.rotation.set(quaternion)` , after calling `calculateTransforms()` the model visually rotates as demanded; the method actually has to be called, otherwise nothing viewable results.
Why and how is it different for the translations? @Xoppa could you please also have a look at my other question to verify the answer given there, for euler rotation order in libgdx (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633455/rotation-order-for-eulers-getpitch-getroll-getyaw-from-quaternion-in-lib)

Comment: for the translations, goal is with human model: 
From rotating a leg, the foot is translated in global World. The difference in translation between previous &posteriour state should be added to the Hips, so that (when later on the foot is „fixed on ground“ by resetting its global position to origin) the human stands up (because the hips move up). Is there a better way doing it in libgdx with e.g. are there existing IK solvers?

Comment: It is very unclear what you exactly mean. If you have another question then you can better ask a new question. Comments are not suited for that.